# Can I use Named Credentials with my SOAP service that requires authentication in the envolope?

Tags: apex, soap-api, namedcredentials

My SOAP payload has an authentication node within the payload like this:

```
<CustomInterface>
 <Header>
  <Environment>Sandbox</Environment>
  <Login>
   <User>username</User>
   <Password>1234</Password>
  </Login>
 </Header>
....
</CustomInterface>
```

I want to know can I use Named Credentials to populate the Login node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if *[Allow Merge Fields in HTTP Body](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials_custom_headers_bodies.htm)* is enabled, you can use the [supported merge fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials_merge_fields.htm):

```
<CustomInterface>
 <Header>
  <Environment>Sandbox</Environment>
  <Login>
   <User>{!$Credential.Username}</User>
   <Password>{!$Credential.Password}</Password>
  </Login>
 </Header>
....
</CustomInterface>
```